# “…easy enough, except…” Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

I heard this line in the movie "The social network". The full line is "The truth is she has a nice face. I need to do something to take my mind off her. Easy enough, except I need an idea." What I know is that the meaning of the word "except" means "not including" or "other than" . I am sure he is not saying "something except an idea". How does this line make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence should be understood as 'In theory this should be easy, however I need an idea with which I can replace my thoughts of her'

Comment: So, you're saying 'except' also means 'however' ?

Comment: @user Yes, basically. It means ‘apart from the fact that’.

Comment: Yes. It's counter-intuitive; the expected recoverable full expression would be 'This **is** easy enough', which wouldn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

It means "this would be easy, but it is not easy because I need an idea" - an idea is the only exception to the fact that this task is easy